# How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to return a string with all of the contents of a CSS rule, like the format you'd see in an inline style. I'd like to be able to do this without knowing what is contained in a particular rule, so I can't just pull them out by style name (like `.style.width` etc.)

The CSS:

```
.test {
    width:80px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#808080;
}
```

The code so far:

```
function getStyle(className) {
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
    for(var x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
        if(classes[x].selectorText==className) {
            //this is where I can collect the style information, but how?
        }
    }
}
getStyle('.test')
```

Comment: please check this also.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53592919/how-could-we-find-the-stylesheets-of-a-page-which-is-insided-any-iframe

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Adapted from [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/cssrule.shtml), building on scunliffe's answer:

```
function getStyle(className) {
    var cssText = "";
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {        
        if (classes[x].selectorText == className) {
            cssText += classes[x].cssText || classes[x].style.cssText;
        }         
    }
    return cssText;
}

alert(getStyle('.test'));
```

Comment: Note that className must exactly match the selector used in CSS file. For example getStyle(".article a") won't find anything if a style has been described like this ".article a, article a:hover { color: #ccc; }".

Comment: This does not work in chrome, but it works in firefox, what could be the problem??

Comment: if there are multiple stylesheets, then you will also need to loop through those as well.for(var i=0;i<document.styleSheets.length;i++) {    
        var s = document.styleSheets[i];}

Comment: @surya See my answer for a adapted full working solution

Comment: @Johnydep `var classes` should be `document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].cssRules` in Chrome. This could be (creatively) added to the shim in the answer.

Comment: Even still, in late March 2020, this doesn't work in Chrome, per Vilius Paulauskas's comment from back in September 2011. I came up with a complete code that works (DISCLAIMER: I only tested it on Chrome.) idk whether to revise this answer with it, since it is accepted answer, or create my own answer.

Answer (score 28):

Since the accepted answer from "nsdel" is only avilable with one stylesheet in a document this is the adapted full working solution:

```
    /**
     * Gets styles by a classname
     * 
     * @notice The className must be 1:1 the same as in the CSS
     * @param string className_
     */
    function getStyle(className_) {

        var styleSheets = window.document.styleSheets;
        var styleSheetsLength = styleSheets.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < styleSheetsLength; i++){
            var classes = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;
            if (!classes)
                continue;
            var classesLength = classes.length;
            for (var x = 0; x < classesLength; x++) {
                if (classes[x].selectorText == className_) {
                    var ret;
                    if(classes[x].cssText){
                        ret = classes[x].cssText;
                    } else {
                        ret = classes[x].style.cssText;
                    }
                    if(ret.indexOf(classes[x].selectorText) == -1){
                        ret = classes[x].selectorText + "{" + ret + "}";
                    }
                    return ret;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Notice: The selector must be the same as in the CSS.

Comment: `global_` ist just a alias for the window object. I've edited the code snippet. It should work now

Comment: your code fails if a stylesheet has no rules or cssRules (which can happen!) add 
   if (!classes) continue;
after 
   var classes = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;
            var classesLength = classes.length;
see my edit

Comment: works, but should return a object instead of a string

Comment: @kofifus Your approach has been added

Comment: Note that this doesn't work since GC versio 64.0: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753691/cannot-access-cssrules-from-local-css-file-in-chrome-64/49160760#49160760

Comment: `var classes = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;` will throw an exceptions if style is external and CORS is not good

Answer (score 18):

## SOLUTION 1 (CROSS-BROWSER)

```
function GetProperty(classOrId,property)
{ 
    var FirstChar = classOrId.charAt(0);  var Remaining= classOrId.substring(1);
    var elem = (FirstChar =='#') ?  document.getElementById(Remaining) : document.getElementsByClassName(Remaining)[0];
    return window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue(property);
}

alert( GetProperty(".my_site_title","position") ) ;
```

## SOLUTION 2 (CROSS-BROWSER)

```
function GetStyle(CLASSname) 
{
    var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    var styleSheetsLength = styleSheets.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < styleSheetsLength; i++){
        if (styleSheets[i].rules ) { var classes = styleSheets[i].rules; }
        else { 
            try {  if(!styleSheets[i].cssRules) {continue;} } 
            //Note that SecurityError exception is specific to Firefox.
            catch(e) { if(e.name == 'SecurityError') { console.log("SecurityError. Cant readd: "+ styleSheets[i].href);  continue; }}
            var classes = styleSheets[i].cssRules ;
        }
        for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
            if (classes[x].selectorText == CLASSname) {
                var ret = (classes[x].cssText) ? classes[x].cssText : classes[x].style.cssText ;
                if(ret.indexOf(classes[x].selectorText) == -1){ret = classes[x].selectorText + "{" + ret + "}";}
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
}

alert( GetStyle('.my_site_title') );
```

Comment: Sadly, by now the problem is basically unsolvable universally in a good way.
The 1st solution does not work since at times the browser still did not finish the computing of styles so it does not return a correct value yet (a reason to read actual CSS rules). And there is no event to listen to for this.
The 2nd solution only works on your own styles as both FF & Chrome (and maybe others) throw a 'Security Error' due to CORS violation when you try to access style sheets. The only way is ugly: to use `setInterval` waiting for styles to be computed if you know that values might change.

Answer (score 7):

I've found none of the suggestions to really work.  Here's a more robust one that normalizes spacing when finding classes.

```
//Inside closure so that the inner functions don't need regeneration on every call.
const getCssClasses = (function () {
    function normalize(str) {
        if (!str)  return '';
        str = String(str).replace(/\s*([>~+])\s*/g, ' $1 ');  //Normalize symbol spacing.
        return str.replace(/(\s+)/g, ' ').trim();           //Normalize whitespace
    }
    function split(str, on) {               //Split, Trim, and remove empty elements
        return str.split(on).map(x => x.trim()).filter(x => x);
    }
    function containsAny(selText, ors) {
        return selText ? ors.some(x => selText.indexOf(x) >= 0) : false;
    }
    return function (selector) {
        const logicalORs = split(normalize(selector), ',');
        const sheets = Array.from(window.document.styleSheets);
        const ruleArrays = sheets.map((x) => Array.from(x.rules || x.cssRules || []));
        const allRules = ruleArrays.reduce((all, x) => all.concat(x), []);
        return allRules.filter((x) => containsAny(normalize(x.selectorText), logicalORs));
    };
})();
```

Here's it in action from the Chrome console.

[image]

Comment: This is the mecha of all the answers on this page. I would even go as far as to say this should be on github

Comment: This doesn't work in IE11, because Array.map() with the provided syntax is not supported.
I'd suggest changing it to the old function(){ return xxx; } syntax for better compatibility.
Otherwise, great answer!

Comment: I modified this to work with IE11 (e.g. ES5).
Here's a JSFiddle with everything you need: https://jsfiddle.net/xp5r8961/

Answer (score 6):

Some browser differences to be aware of:

Given the CSS:

```
div#a { ... }
div#b, div#c { ... }
```

and given InsDel's example, classes will have **2 classes in FF and 3 classes in IE7**.

My example illustrates this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
    div#a { }
    div#b, div#c { }
    </style>
    <script>
    function PrintRules() {
    var rules = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
        for(var x=0;x<rules.length;x++) {
            document.getElementById("rules").innerHTML += rules[x].selectorText + "<br />";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input onclick="PrintRules()" type="button" value="Print Rules" /><br />
    RULES:
    <div id="rules"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function getStyle(className) {
    document.styleSheets.item("menu").cssRules.item(className).cssText;
}
getStyle('.test')
```

Note : "menu" is an element ID which you have applied CSS.
"className" a css class name which we need to get its text.

Comment: Are you sure this is working? (AFAIK the `item` method takes an integer index, not a className).

Comment: complete nonsense

Answer (score 3):

Here is code to iterate through all rules in a page:

```js
function iterateCSS(f) {
  for (const styleSheet of window.document.styleSheets) {
    const classes = styleSheet.rules || styleSheet.cssRules;
    if (!classes) continue;

    for (const cssRule of classes) {
      if (cssRule.type !== 1 || !cssRule.style) continue;
      const selector = cssRule.selectorText, style=cssRule.style;
      if (!selector || !style.cssText) continue;
      for (let i=0; i<style.length; i++) {
        const propertyName=style.item(i);
        if (f(selector, propertyName, style.getPropertyValue(propertyName), style.getPropertyPriority(propertyName), cssRule)===false) return;
      }
    }
  }
}

iterateCSS( (selector, propertyName, propertyValue, propertyPriority, cssRule) => {
  console.log(selector+' { '+propertyName+': '+propertyValue+(propertyPriority==='important' ? ' !important' : '')+' }');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a similar helper  function 
which shows the unneeded styles for this page. appends a `<div>` to the body listing all styles that where not used.

(to be used with the firebug console)

```
(function getStyles(){var CSSrules,allRules,CSSSheets, unNeeded, currentRule;
CSSSheets=document.styleSheets;

for(j=0;j<CSSSheets.length;j++){
for(i=0;i<CSSSheets[j].cssRules.length;i++){
    currentRule = CSSSheets[j].cssRules[i].selectorText;

    if(!document.querySelectorAll(currentRule).length){ 
       unNeeded+=CSSSheets[j].cssRules[i].cssText+"<br>"; 
  }       
 }
}

docBody=document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
allRulesContainer=document.createElement("div");
docBody.appendChild(allRulesContainer);
allRulesContainer.innerHTML=unNeeded+isHover;
return false
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Have adapted julmot's answer in order to get a more complete result. This method will also return styles where the class is part for the selector.

```
//Get all styles where the provided class is involved
//Input parameters should be css selector such as .myClass or #m
//returned as an array of tuples {selectorText:"", styleDefinition:""}
function getStyleWithCSSSelector(cssSelector) {
    var styleSheets = window.document.styleSheets;
    var styleSheetsLength = styleSheets.length;
    var arStylesWithCSSSelector = [];

    //in order to not find class which has the current name as prefix
    var arValidCharsAfterCssSelector = [" ", ".", ",", "#",">","+",":","["];

    //loop through all the stylessheets in the bor
    for(var i = 0; i < styleSheetsLength; i++){
        var classes = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;
        var classesLength = classes.length;
        for (var x = 0; x < classesLength; x++) {
            //check for any reference to the class in the selector string
            if(typeof classes[x].selectorText != "undefined"){
                var matchClass = false;

                if(classes[x].selectorText === cssSelector){//exact match
                    matchClass=true;
                }else {//check for it as part of the selector string
                    //TODO: Optimize with regexp
                    for (var j=0;j<arValidCharsAfterCssSelector.length; j++){
                        var cssSelectorWithNextChar = cssSelector+ arValidCharsAfterCssSelector[j];

                        if(classes[x].selectorText.indexOf(cssSelectorWithNextChar)!=-1){
                            matchClass=true;
                            //break out of for-loop
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(matchClass === true){
                    //console.log("Found "+ cssSelectorWithNextChar + " in css class definition " + classes[x].selectorText);
                    var styleDefinition;
                    if(classes[x].cssText){
                        styleDefinition = classes[x].cssText;
                    } else {
                        styleDefinition = classes[x].style.cssText;
                    }
                    if(styleDefinition.indexOf(classes[x].selectorText) == -1){
                        styleDefinition = classes[x].selectorText + "{" + styleDefinition + "}";
                    }
                    arStylesWithCSSSelector.push({"selectorText":classes[x].selectorText, "styleDefinition":styleDefinition});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(arStylesWithCSSSelector.length==0) {
        return null;
    }else {
        return arStylesWithCSSSelector;    
    }
}
```

In addition, I've made a function which collects the css style definitions to the sub-tree of a root node your provide (through a jquery selector).

```
function getAllCSSClassDefinitionsForSubtree(selectorOfRootElement){
    //stack in which elements are pushed and poped from
    var arStackElements = [];
    //dictionary for checking already added css class definitions
    var existingClassDefinitions = {}

    //use jquery for selecting root element
    var rootElement = $(selectorOfRootElement)[0];
    //string with the complete CSS output
    var cssString = "";

    console.log("Fetching all classes used in sub tree of " +selectorOfRootElement);
    arStackElements.push(rootElement);
    var currentElement;

    while(currentElement = arStackElements.pop()){
        currentElement = $(currentElement);
        console.log("Processing element " + currentElement.attr("id"));

        //Look at class attribute of element 
        var classesString = currentElement.attr("class");
        if(typeof classesString != 'undefined'){
            var arClasses = classesString.split(" ");

            //for each class in the current element
            for(var i=0; i< arClasses.length; i++){

                //fetch the CSS Styles for a single class. Need to append the . char to indicate its a class
                var arStylesWithCSSSelector = getStyleWithCSSSelector("."+arClasses[i]);
                console.log("Processing class "+ arClasses[i]);

                if(arStylesWithCSSSelector != null){
                    //console.log("Found "+ arStylesWithCSSSelector.length + " CSS style definitions for class " +arClasses[i]);
                    //append all found styles to the cssString
                    for(var j=0; j< arStylesWithCSSSelector.length; j++){
                        var tupleStyleWithCSSSelector = arStylesWithCSSSelector[j];

                        //check if it has already been added
                        if(typeof existingClassDefinitions[tupleStyleWithCSSSelector.selectorText] === "undefined"){
                            //console.log("Adding " + tupleStyleWithCSSSelector.styleDefinition);
                            cssString+= tupleStyleWithCSSSelector.styleDefinition;
                            existingClassDefinitions[tupleStyleWithCSSSelector.selectorText] = true;
                        }else {
                            //console.log("Already added " + tupleStyleWithCSSSelector.styleDefinition);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //push all child elments to stack
        if(currentElement.children().length>0){
            arStackElements= arStackElements.concat(currentElement.children().toArray());
        }
    }

    console.log("Found " + Object.keys(existingClassDefinitions).length + " CSS class definitions");
    return cssString;
}
```

Note that if a class is defined several times with the same selector, the above function will only pick up the first. Note that the example uses jQuery (but cab relatively easily be rewritten to not use it)

Comment: would be great to have a non jquery solution (and a jsfiddle ..)

Answer (score 1):

```
const getStyle = query => [...document.querySelector(query).computedStyleMap().entries()].map(e=>(e[1]+=[],e)).map(e=>e.join`:`+';').join`\n`
```

In one line, prints out generated css for any query.

Answer (score 0):

//works in IE, not sure about other browsers...

```
alert(classes[x].style.cssText);
```

Answer (score 0):

This version will go through all of the stylesheets on a page. For my needs, the styles were usually in the 2nd to last of the 20+ stylesheets, so I check them backwards.

```
    var getStyle = function(className){
        var x, sheets,classes;
        for( sheets=document.styleSheets.length-1; sheets>=0; sheets-- ){
            classes = document.styleSheets[sheets].rules || document.styleSheets[sheets].cssRules;
            for(x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
                if(classes[x].selectorText===className) {
                    return  (classes[x].cssText ? classes[x].cssText : classes[x].style.cssText);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I added return of object where attributes are parsed out style/values:

```
var getClassStyle = function(className){
    var x, sheets,classes;
    for( sheets=document.styleSheets.length-1; sheets>=0; sheets-- ){
        classes = document.styleSheets[sheets].rules || document.styleSheets[sheets].cssRules;
        for(x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
            if(classes[x].selectorText===className){
                classStyleTxt = (classes[x].cssText ? classes[x].cssText : classes[x].style.cssText).match(/\{\s*([^{}]+)\s*\}/)[1];
                var classStyles = {};
                var styleSets = classStyleTxt.match(/([^;:]+:\s*[^;:]+\s*)/g);
                for(y=0;y<styleSets.length;y++){
                    var style = styleSets[y].match(/\s*([^:;]+):\s*([^;:]+)/);
                    if(style.length > 2)
                        classStyles[style[1]]=style[2];
                }
                return classStyles;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Comment: ``style.cssText.match(...).1`` is null or not an object

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: classStyleTxt is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I created a version that searches all stylesheets and returns matches as a key/value object. You can also specify **startsWith** to match child styles.

```js
getStylesBySelector('.pure-form-html', true);
```

returns:

```json
{
    ".pure-form-html body": "padding: 0; margin: 0; font-size: 14px; font-family: tahoma;",
    ".pure-form-html h1": "margin: 0; font-size: 18px; font-family: tahoma;"
}
```

from:

```css
.pure-form-html body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: tahoma;
}

.pure-form-html h1 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: tahoma;
}
```

The code:

```js
/**
 * Get all CSS style blocks matching a CSS selector from stylesheets
 * @param {string} className - class name to match
 * @param {boolean} startingWith - if true matches all items starting with selector, default = false (exact match only)
 * @example getStylesBySelector('pure-form .pure-form-html ')
 * @returns {object} key/value object containing matching styles otherwise null
 */
function getStylesBySelector(className, startingWith) {

    if (!className || className === '') throw new Error('Please provide a css class name');

    var styleSheets = window.document.styleSheets;
    var result = {};

    // go through all stylesheets in the DOM
    for (var i = 0, l = styleSheets.length; i < l; i++) {

        var classes = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules || [];

        // go through all classes in each document
        for (var x = 0, ll = classes.length; x < ll; x++) {

            var selector = classes[x].selectorText || '';
            var content = classes[x].cssText || classes[x].style.cssText || '';

            // if the selector matches
            if ((startingWith && selector.indexOf(className) === 0) || selector === className) {

                // create an object entry with selector as key and value as content
                result[selector] = content.split(/(?:{|})/)[1].trim();
            }
        }
    }

    // only return object if we have values, otherwise null
    return Object.keys(result).length > 0 ? result : null;
}
```

I'm using this in production as part of the [pure-form](https://github.com/john-doherty/pure-form) project. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not working. CORS exception! `Uncaught DOMException: CSSStyleSheet.cssRules getter: Not allowed to access cross-origin stylesheet`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getStyle(cssClass){
    let result = '';
    let styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (let i = 0, j = styleSheets.length; i < j; i++) {
        let classes = styleSheets[i].cssRules;
        if (classes && classes.length) {
            for (let x = 0, y = classes.length; x < y; x++) {
                let selectorText = classes[x].selectorText;
                if (selectorText && selectorText.includes(cssClass)) {
                    let rules = selectorText.split(',');
                    for (let n = 0, m = rules.length; n < m; n++) {
                        let rule = rules[n];
                        if (rule) {
                            let rulePath = rule.trim().split(' ');
                            let p = rulePath[rulePath.length - 1];
                            if (p === cssClass) {
                                let ret = classes[x].cssText || classes[x].style.cssText || '';
                                let css = ret.match(/{[\w\W]*}/);
                                let cssText = css[0] ? css[0].substring(1, css[0].length - 1).trim() : '';
                                result += cssText;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
function setInlineStyle(node){
   
    let inlineStyle = node.style.cssText;
    node.classList.forEach(className => {
        node.style.cssText += getStyle('.' + className);
    })
    node.style.cssText += inlineStyle;
    node.removeAttribute('class');
}
let div = document.querySelector('.div-block');
setInlineStyle(div);
```

```css
.div-block{
position:absolute;
background-color:red;
width:300px;
height:300px;
border:solid 1px blue;
border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="div-block">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
function getStyle(cssClass){
    let result = '';
    let styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    for (let i = 0, j = styleSheets.length; i < j; i++) {
        let classes = styleSheets[i].cssRules;
        if (classes && classes.length) {
            for (let x = 0, y = classes.length; x < y; x++) {
                let selectorText = classes[x].selectorText;
                if (selectorText && selectorText.includes(cssClass)) {
                    let rules = selectorText.split(',');
                    for (let n = 0, m = rules.length; n < m; n++) {
                        let rule = rules[n];
                        if (rule) {
                            let rulePath = rule.trim().split(' ');
                            let p = rulePath[rulePath.length - 1];
                            if (p === cssClass) {
                                let ret = classes[x].cssText || classes[x].style.cssText || '';
                                let css = ret.match(/{[\w\W]*}/);
                                let cssText = css[0] ? css[0].substring(1, css[0].length - 1).trim() : '';
                                result += cssText;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
function setInlineStyle(node){
   
    let inlineStyle = node.style.cssText;
    node.classList.forEach(className => {
        node.style.cssText += getStyle('.' + className);
    })
    node.style.cssText += inlineStyle;
    node.removeAttribute('class');
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem.
And with the help of guys I came up with a really smart solution that solve that problem totally (run on chrome ) .

Extract all images from the network

````js
 function AllImagesUrl (domain){
  return  performance.getEntries()
    .filter( e=> 
       e.initiatorType == "img" &&
       new RegExp(domain).test(e.name) 
    )
  .map( e=> e.name.replace('some cleaning work here','') ) ```
````

Answer (score -2):

Based on @dude answer this should return relevant styles in a object, for instance:

```
.recurly-input {                                                                                                                                                                             
  display: block;                                                                                                                                                                            
  border-radius: 2px;                                                                                                                                                                        
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;                                                                                                                                                                
  outline: 0;                                                                                                                                                                                
  box-shadow: none;                                                                                                                                                                          
  border: 1px solid #beb7b3;                                                                                                                                                                 
  padding: 0.6em;                                                                                                                                                                            
  background-color: #f7f7f7;                                                                                                                                                                 
  width:100%;                                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

This will return:

```
backgroundColor:
"rgb(247, 247, 247)"
border
:
"1px solid rgb(190, 183, 179)"
borderBottom
:
"1px solid rgb(190, 183, 179)"
borderBottomColor
:
"rgb(190, 183, 179)"
borderBottomLeftRadius
:
"2px"
borderBottomRightRadius
:
"2px"
borderBottomStyle
:
"solid"
borderBottomWidth
:
"1px"
borderColor
:
"rgb(190, 183, 179)"
borderLeft
:
"1px solid rgb(190, 183, 179)"
borderLeftColor
:
"rgb(190, 183, 179)"
borderLeftStyle
:
"solid"
borderLeftWidth
:
"1px"
borderRadius
:
"2px"
borderRight
:
"1px solid rgb(190, 183, 179)"
borderRightColor
:
"rgb(190, 183, 179)"
borderRightStyle
:
"solid"
borderRightWidth
:
"1px"
borderStyle
:
"solid"
borderTop
:
"1px solid rgb(190, 183, 179)"
borderTopColor
:
"rgb(190, 183, 179)"
borderTopLeftRadius
:
"2px"
borderTopRightRadius
:
"2px"
borderTopStyle
:
"solid"
borderTopWidth
:
"1px"
borderWidth
:
"1px"
boxShadow
:
"none"
display
:
"block"
outline
:
"0px"
outlineWidth
:
"0px"
padding
:
"0.6em"
paddingBottom
:
"0.6em"
paddingLeft
:
"0.6em"
paddingRight
:
"0.6em"
paddingTop
:
"0.6em"
width
:
"100%"
```

Code:

```
function getStyle(className_) {

    var styleSheets = window.document.styleSheets;
    var styleSheetsLength = styleSheets.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < styleSheetsLength; i++){
        var classes = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;
        if (!classes)
            continue;
        var classesLength = classes.length;
        for (var x = 0; x < classesLength; x++) {
            if (classes[x].selectorText == className_) {
                return _.pickBy(classes[x].style, (v, k) => isNaN(parseInt(k)) && typeof(v) == 'string' && v && v != 'initial' && k != 'cssText' )
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: anything without lodash in use? _.pickBy doesn't exist otherwise.

Comment: k & v are reversed based on what you're asking of them....  should be return `_.pickBy(classes[x].style, (k,v) => isNaN(parseInt(k)) && typeof(v) == 'string' && v && v != 'initial' && k != 'cssText' )`