# How do I access the individual styles of a CSS rule-set using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

If I have a style defined using a class selector:

```
.example {
width: 50px;
}
```

And in JavaScript, I would like to get the value of the width property for that rule-set, without using some reference to a concrete element that uses that rule-set. I want something which would give me the output "50" or "50px" given the input of "example" and "width".

Comment: are you using a library like jQuery?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

See this entry on using `document.styleSheets` to access CSS rules on [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html).

**EDIT:** I do agree with others here though in that if this is an important requirement you'll have a much easier time of it if you leverage one of the mentioned libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to do it without creating an element that uses that class. I'd create an invisible div with the class and query that div.

Comment: Hypothetically: Another rule-set is `div { width: 10px !important; }`, you get that width instead of the one for the rule-set with the class selector.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those times when I do recommend the use of a library.

There are a couple of different methods to access stylesheets attached to a document, and different browsers support different ones.

The [YUI 2 StyleSheet Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/stylesheet/) will smooth out the differences for you, although you would have to search through the rules to find the one that you were looking for.