# How know if there is a style for an id or a class?

Tags: javascript

```
// instead of 'width' could be 'font-size', 'color', 'position', etc
var result = getCSS('some_id_name_or_class_name', 'width');

// may be the value or 'null' if there is no style for such an id name or a class name
alert(result);
```

(The matter is that there is yet no element created with such id or class.)

Comment: Do you want to get the `style` declaration for that element, or the *computed* style (= the sum of all styles that affect that element)?

Comment: Also, your two requirements are wildly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the [getStyle method from QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html) a shot (it only works with Ids though, but you could modify it):

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    var x = document.getElementById(el);
    if (x.currentStyle)
         var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
         var y = document.defaultView
                         .getComputedStyle(x,null)
                         .getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

You should definitely make a trip to the link though. There are some quirks (different browsers expect the styleProp parameter to be in different formats.

Again, you can use this as a base and build out the functionality you need (like hiding the cross-browser issues, making it work with classes, etc.).

**EDIT**

Since you're not looking to get computed values, you can use the document.styleSheets collection to read the values out of your CSS:

[W3C DOM tests - styleSheets](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/tests/stylesheets.html)

Again, there are some cross-browser implementation details (cssRules vs. rules) but you can write your code to work around those.

Comment: Justin, the matter is that there is yet no element created with such id or class.

Comment: @Soverin - You need to have an element on the page before you can get computed style values for it.

Comment: Nope, I do not need computed style, just declared style. The element is to be created under such an id name or a class name. And I need to know whether to use style declared by user or set a default style.

Comment: @Soverin - Why do you need the styles before the element is added to the page rather than after?

Comment: Because this JavaScript program allows users to set up some styles as css and if any styles declared it uses those, if not it uses its default styles.

Comment: Also, here's something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript

Answer (score -2):

http://jquery.com/

jQuery is great for this kind of stuff.

```
alert($("#yourIdHere").css("whateverCssPropertyYouWant"));
```

Comment: jQuery is prohibited in our country =(

Comment: jQuery is great for this, but you probably want to provide a code example too.

Comment: @Soverin - seriously? I didn't know any countries have a ban on javascript libraries...

Comment: @Soverin what country is that?

Comment: Yep, the government only bans jQuery.

Comment: Wow, maybe prototype then? http://www.prototypejs.org/ Otherwise it's not fun to get at the correct computed style cross-browserly

Comment: Oh for goodness sake `.css()` doesn't take a selector as its argument - http://api.jquery.com/css/. If you're going to use jQuery then *at least use it correctly*