# Print list of attributes from a CSS class

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

I tried to print the list of attributes values in a specific CSS class with the getElementsByClassName method like below :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .toto {
                width:200px;
                height:50px;
                background-color:red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="lol" class="toto"></div>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var toto = document.getElementsByClassName('toto');
            if (toto) {
                for (int i; i < toto.length; i++)
                    document.write(toto[i]);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But toto.length = 1 in all cases. I would like to print the values '200px', '50px' et 'red'. Does anyone can help me ? Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns the **DOM elements** with said class (and there is only one). It does not let you access the CSS rules of that class. For a solution, have a look at the bottom of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4097138/218196).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get a reference to an element through JavaScript you can generally only get CSS properties that have been set through inline CSS using the style-attribute of the element. Properties applied through CSS can not be read through the element as properties of that element.

You can however use [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) within your loop to get the final computed CSS that has been applied to the element.

In your case it would be something like:

```
var toto = document.getElementsByClassName('toto');
if (toto) {
   for (int i; i < toto.length; i++)
      // Log the height of each element
      console.log(getComputedStyle(toto[i], null).getPropertyValue("height"));
   }
}
```

***Notice that the browser-support is somewhat limited (IE9+).***

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood what `getElementsByClassName` does.

`getElementsByClassName` returns all HTML elements (tags) that have a class assigned - in your example this is one `div`, which is why `toto.length == 1`.

I'm not aware of any DOM methods for enumerating properties for a given CSS selector. However you can use tools like [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) or Chrome's developer tools to inspect elements and see which CSS rules have been applied, and which properties have been modified.

Answer (score 0):

I won't repeat what others have yet pointed regarding `getElementsByClassName` returning more than one elements, but I think your approach isn't the best one if you're interested in knowing what's in your style and not what's in a specific element (on which many styles are usually applied).

Here's a solution working even without element having the class `toto` :

```
function findStyle(selector) {
  for (var i=document.styleSheets.length; i-->0;) {
    for (var j = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules.length; j-->0;) {
      var r = document.styleSheets[i].cssRules[j];
      if (r.selectorText==selector) return r;
    }
  }
}
var style = findStyle('.toto');
console.log(style.style.width, style.style.height, style.style['background-color']);
```

This logs on the console `200px 50px red`

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ULDEC/)