# get all css classes background & color properties values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, arrays

I want to get all background and color properties values of all CSS declarations.

For example:

```
    body {
      background: #fff;
    }
    .aaa {
      background: #dedede;
      color: #000
    }
    .text {
      color: #333;
      padding: 10px
    }
```

I want to get an output like this and the values of these properties need to be stored in an array.

```
    body {
      background: #fff;
    }
    .aaa {
      background: #dedede;
      color: #000
    }
    .text {
      color: #333;
    }
```

I tried to do this using jQuery. I can get the background property value of one specific class like `.aaa` or `.text`. How do I get the values of all classes?

```
$('#btn-invert').on('click', function() {
  var color = $("body").css("background");
  // var test = invertColor("#00a3fe"); 
  console.log(color); 
});
```

Comment: refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318209/print-list-of-attributes-from-a-css-class

Comment: *"I want to get output like this and these properties need to be stored in array."* - You want output as a formatted string _and_ as an array? What would the array format be?

Comment: @nnnnnn like this ["#fff", "#dedede", "#000", "#333"]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To read style use `document.styleSheets` which contains all information (`let cssArr=...` in snippet). When you read it into your array then you can generate string from that array (`let genCssStr` in snippet). The colors read in this way are in format e.g. `rgb(255, 255, 255)` so we need to convert them to hex (by `rgbToHex` src [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54014428/860099))

```js
const rgbToHex = (rgbStr) => rgbStr && '#'+rgbStr.slice(4,-1).split(',').map(x => (+x).toString(16).padStart(2, '0')).join('');

const styles = document.styleSheets;

let cssArr =[...styles[0].cssRules].map(x=> ({ 
  class:      x.selectorText, 
  color:      rgbToHex(x.style.color),
  background: rgbToHex(x.style.background),   
}));

let genCssStr=''; cssArr.forEach(x=> genCssStr+=`
${x.class} {
  ${(x.background ? 'background: '+x.background : '')}
  ${(x.color ? 'color: '+x.color : '')}
}
`.replace(/^  \n/gm,'')); // remove empty lines 

console.log("array:", JSON.stringify(cssArr));
console.log("text:\n", genCssStr);
```

```css
body {
      background: #fff;
    }
    .aaa {
      background: #dedede;
      color: #000
    }
    .text {
      color: #333;
      padding: 10px
    }
```

Comment: nice answer but please add explanation

Comment: array: [{"class":"body","color":"","background":"#ffffNaN"},{"class":".myClass","color":"#000000","background":"#dedeNaN"},{"class":".myClass2","color":"#333333","background":"#ffffNaN"}]

Comment: @VipinKumarSoni can you show you css for colors? I use some simple `rgbToHex` function which works with OP styles - but you can find more sophisticated `rgbToHex` version in stackOverflow (but this is not topic of OP question so I will not dig into it in this answer)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski got this error -> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules

Comment: @Karuppiah this is separate problem (and question)  - may be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088507/cannot-access-rules-in-external-cssstylesheet) answer will helps - if not find/ask question on stackoverflow. In case of CORS problem you will probably be unable to use this solution (in direct way or at all)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>jQuery Tests</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(function(){
            var myArray = [];
            $("*").each(function() {
                var oneArray = [];
                var tag = $(this).prop("tagName");
                var classname = $(this).attr("class") ? $(this).attr("class") : "N/A";
                var background = $(this).css("background-color");
                var color = $(this).css("color");

                oneArray["tag"] = tag;
                oneArray["classname"] = classname;
                oneArray["background"] = background;
                oneArray["color"] = color;

                myArray.push(oneArray);                                             
            });
            console.log(myArray);
        });
        </script>
        <style>
        body {
          background: #fff;
        }
        .myClass {
            background: #dedede;
            color: #000
        }
        .myClass2 {
            color: #333;
            background: #fff;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a class="myClass" href="#">link</a>
        <div class="myClass2"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```