# How to know if element height or width was set in javascript/css?

Tags: css, height

Is there any way to know if an element **height** or **width** was set (not auto) in javascript/css ?
elm.style.height will only return a value if the height is defined inside the element attribute list : **<div style='height:200px' .... ></div>**, otherwise it will always return an empty string even if you define the height inside a style tag or a css file : **.myElmCss{height:200px}**.

On the other hand, using window.getComputedStyle() or elm.currentStyle will always return a value even if no height was defined neither inside the element attribute list nor in a css file/style tag.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand the answer, could you explain more clearly?

Comment: Well, suppose these 2 elements : 1- <div class='myElm'>inner content ... </div> and 2- <div>inner content ... </div>, and the css class : .myElm{height:200px;}. In both cases you can't tell if the element height is auto (like in the 2nd case) or not (1st case). How would you do ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this post [How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)

To do what you're looking for it appears to be a matter of iterating over the stylesheets to find declared properties.  You would probably also cross reference with inline styles like you mentioned in your question.

from [@InsDel's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript/324533#324533):

```
function getStyle(className) {
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
    for(var x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
        if(classes[x].selectorText==className) {
                (classes[x].cssText) ? alert(classes[x].cssText) : alert(classes[x].style.cssText);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @InsDel. I already thought about something like this, I personally was hoping a function or something less heavy than iterating through all the document style list. I think I'm going to stick to that. thanks again.

Comment: Hi @InsDel, will this work if the element style is defined by its id instead of its class, like : #myElm{height:200ppx}.

Comment: sorry @InsDel, I didn't vote for your answer I'm not registered.

Comment: Forget the question about the id, I just read the post you mentioned,  it works even for a class defined by id. thanks.

Comment: What about Jquery? `$('element').width();` o.O

Comment: @TomSarduy the jQuery function returns the computed value, i.e. it will never return "auto" or "100%" - it will always return pixels.