# Is it possible add or change CSS properties using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Specifically, a `class` or `id` within the css.

Would you use something similar to `$(window).height()`?

Comment: `$(…)` is some function from a javascript framework. That's not a native javascript function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you want, but as a general rule all the styles applied to a given element can be accessed in JavaScript using something like:

`element.style.<property-name>`

So using native JavaScript you can do:

```
var elemStyles = document.getElementById("someId").style;
var styleWidth = elemStyles.width;
```

Assuming at least one element with a given CSS class and a framework that can select elements by class, you can similarly do:

```
var elemStyles = $(".someClass")[0].style;
var styleWidth = elemStyles.width;
```

Or depending upon what (if any) JavaScript framework you are using, there may be specialized methods that you can use to access/inspect various CSS attributes for a given element.

Note that any of these methods will bring back *all* the styles applied to the element, whether they are coming from the CSS file, from inline CSS declarations, or added programmatically by a script on the page.  If you want to get *just* the styles inherited from the CSS file, then things get a bit trickier.

Comment: I'd like to change the amount of pixels a div animates left for (using jquery), depending on the width of the div next to it (which changes), hence the need to retrieve with width and insert it into a variable. Or is there a better way?

Comment: @NorthernLights - Using jQuery, I'd recommend just using something like `$("#otherElemId").width()` to get the width.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible

if you would like to receive other css properties check this out
http://api.jquery.com/css

you would do somethig like this

```
var cssvalue = $(selector).css(propertyName);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will probably help you, too. Esp. if you want to do it without jQuery: [How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)