# Read CSS rule values with JavaScript in the most recent browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The following question has been already asked [Read CSS rule values with JavaScript? - Nov 27 '08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript).

I tried the same code on my browser `google chrome 19.0.1084.46` and `firefox 12.0` and the script does not work.

Is there a new script, library, maybe using jQuery, to active the same task on the most recent version of browsers today ?

---

Here the code which does not work:

```
function getStyle(className) {
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
    for(var x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
        if(classes[x].selectorText==className) {
                (classes[x].cssText) ? alert(classes[x].cssText) : alert(classes[x].style.cssText);
        }
    }
}
getStyle('.test')
```

---

Here a link to the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vjD2/1/)

Comment: You may first try the solutions provided in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element/5830517#5830517

Comment: I checked this code on google chrome Version 20.0.1132.8 dev just now. and this seemed to work for me.

Comment: If the $("#elementToGetAllCSS") is not in the document but just in css file how can I get the rule?

Comment: go to this link, maybe I miss something. http://jsfiddle.net/9vjD2/

Comment: well in your fiddle you are alerting a function and since your function does not return anything, the result of undefined is correct
as for the alert inside of the function, if you remove the IF statement to check if the class is test then you will find out why it is not alerting. Don't worry it isn't that many alerts