# trying to get the css left hover property using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, properties, hover

im trying to get the left property using jQuery where the css is written as

```
#sldn_mnu li:hover ul ul {left:-6000;}
```

below is my alert which outputs (-7000) which is the left prop. of this style: #sldn_mnu ul ul {left:-7000;}. any ideas? thanks.

```
alert($('#sldn_mnu li').hover().find('ul ul').css('left'));
```

**relavant html:**
im trying to talk to the secondary < ul> Items 1.1.1 dropdown.

```
<div id="sldn_mnu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HELLO</a></li>
    <li class="sldn_mnu-drop"><a href="#" ><span class="sldn_mnu-label">WORK</span></a>
        <ul>
          <li class="sldn_mnu-subDrop"><a href="#">Item 1.1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#" >Item 1.1.1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" >Item 1.1.2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#" >Item 1.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Item 1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" >Item 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" >Item 2.1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Item 2.2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" >Item 2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Adding the relevant part of your html may help

Comment: You can't really get the css set on pseudo stuff like :hover like that.

Comment: @bruno... i just added in the html snippet. thanks

Comment: i've modified my answer accordingly, however u better of using console.log instead of alert.

Comment: @adeneo not with jQuery functions, but with JavaScript you can.

Comment: @jfrej - nope, you really can't! Searching the stylesheets for a string is'nt really the same as using `element.style`, jQuery or not!

Comment: Ok, I never said it's the same :) You're right. But if you **really** need the content of a pseudo class you'll find it only within a stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to override the 'hover' event and do your things there for example:

JS:

```
$('#sldn_mnu li').bind('hover',function(e){
  //console.log($(this).find('ul ul').css('left'));
  alert($(this).find('ul ul').css('left'));
});​
```

However it would be simpler for you adding a css class to the `<ul>` which you want to ask the `left`, then you could just write:

```
console.log($(this).find('ul.<your_ul_css_class>').css('left'));
```

Another simplifaction would be to add a css class to the `<li>` which you want to trigger the calculation, then all of this could be like:

```
$('li.<your_li_css_class>').bind('hover',function(e){
  console.log($(this).find('ul.<your_ul_css_class>').css('left'));
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If the CSS comes from a stylesheet (and pseudoclasses always do as you can't add them inline), you can't use pure jQuery to retrieve it.

Instead you need to look into the styleSheets objects in `document.styleSheets`.

The following code is adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/324533/206614).
It iterates over all stylesheets and looks for a matching CSS rule.

[Working demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrej/dYH84/1/)

```
function getStyle(selector) {
    for(var y=0;y<document.styleSheets.length;y++){
        var classes = document.styleSheets[y].rules || document.styleSheets[y].cssRules
        for(var x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
            if(classes[x].selectorText.match(selector)) {
                    (classes[x].cssText) ? alert(classes[x].cssText) : alert(classes[x].style.cssText);
            }
        }
    }
}

getStyle(/sldn_mnu.*hover/);
```

Please note, I adapted the function to use a regex match rather than a simple string comparison.

Instead of alerts you might want to return after the first match or perhaps return an array of all matches.