# Is it possible to read the styles of css classes not being used in the DOM using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to be able to read the available css classes of a loaded web page. Not classes that are assigned to DOM elements, but classes that are defined in the CSS. Is this possible with javascript, or specifically jQuery?

I'm attempting a hackish way to override the columns built into the CMS I'm using (concrete5), so bear with me. On load, there will be a number of divs with certain inline percentage widths, such as `style="width: 27%;"`. In my css, there are a number of classes for a grid system, such as `.one`, `.two`, `.three`, etc. that I want to match to these divs.

For example, I have 3 css classes here:

```
.one { width: 8.3333%; }
.two { width: 16.6667%; }
.three { width: 25%; }
```

One of my divs has an inline style of `width: 22%;`. I want to assign it the class that it most closely matches, which is `.three` in this case, and remove the inline style programmatically. Is there a way for me to read what the styles of `.one, .two, .three, etc` are when they're not attached to an element, in other words, read them directly from the css? I want to avoid having to hard-code these values in since they could change.

Answer (score 1):

The width of a CSS class can be obtained like this:

```
function getClassWidth(className) {
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    for (var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
        if (classes[i].selectorText == className) {
            return classes[i].style.getPropertyValue("width");
        }
    }
}

getClassWidth('.one'); // Would return the string "8.3333%"
```

Solution based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript).