# SlickGrid row height based on CSS rule

Tags: javascript, css, slickgrid

Currently I am setting the height of the rows in SlickGrid trough options programatically:

```
var options = {
    rowHeight: 30
};
```

Is there any way I could do it trough CSS rule without modifying slick-grid default implementation?

I am asking this becaous I wan't to set row height based on CSS Media Queries.

My initial idea was to read CSS property programatically (something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/324486/617996)) and set readen value like that:

```
var options = {
    rowHeight: readRowHeightCSSValue()
};
```

...but I am not sure whether this is best idea.

Comment: Have you even tried to overwrite the CSS rules and see what's happening?

Comment: I updated the question. @feeela, overwriting CSS rule will not help as SlickGrid needs rowHeight value internally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue with a little bit different approach as I initially tought, so I am sharing my solution that worked for me.

I used [enquire.js](http://enquire.js) with same CSS media queries as in my stylesheets:

```
enquire.register("only screen and (max-width: 1024px)", {
    match : function() {
        slickGridInitialRowHeight = 15;
    }
}).fire();

enquire.register("only screen and (min-width: 1024px)", {
    match : function() {
        slickGridInitialRowHeight = 30;
    }
}).fire();
```

... after that, I used `slickGridInitialRowHeight` to initialize SlickGrid.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the row height based on the width of the window.

```
rowHeight: $(window).width() < 1024 ? 30 : 15
```

Comment: Will this be consistent with CSS Media Queries?

Comment: It would work the same as your solution unless you wished to use the DPI to determine the row height.