# Checking color value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

So I set the color of the `<body>` with:

```
body
{
    color:Black;
}
```

within the `<head>` and `<style>` tags,
and then I've got various elements in the body, for which if I click them, they call a function. i.e.

```
    <p id="CSE1020" onclick="prereq(this)">CSE1020</p>
```

The prereq function is as follows:

```
function prereq(code) {

    if (code.style.color != "black") {
        code.style.color = "black";
        code.style.fontWeight = "normal";
    }
}
```

And otherwise, if the element is already black, I change the color.
The problem/question is: I have to click the element twice before it changes color.
In other words, its not 'black' initially. The if statement is executed, even though the default color, before it is clicked should be black. How do I get it to recognize that when I first click the element, that it's 'black'?

Comment: What does `code.style.color` give you that first time?

Comment: An empty string, presumably, since the style is not inline with the element.

Comment: grab the colour by running a function in document.ready?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript

Comment: @DavidThomas: How do I get the style to be 'inline' with the element?

Comment: once check the output --   `alert(code.style.color);` (may be issue of case sensitivity)

Comment: It returns an empty string, just like Mr.Thomas said it would

Answer (score 0):

Is jQuery an option? If it is you could do this:http://jsfiddle.net/CxayY/

```
$('#CSE1020').on('click', function(){
    if($('body').css('color')!='black')
    {
        $('body').css('color','black');
        $('body').css('font-weight','normal');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try searching in CSSRules:

```
function prereq(code) {
    var cssRules = window.getMatchedCSSRules(code);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it works when I add the style to the element itself, i.e.

```
    <p id="CSE1020" style="color:black" onclick="prereq(this)">CSE1020</p>
```