# Get an elements style inherited from classes *not* style attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I get the style of a div, that is being applied from stylesheets/style **tags** and ignore the element style programmatically?

e.g.

```js
var alice = 'alice ' + $('.alice').css('color');
var boblice = 'alice ' + $('.bob').css('color');
var bob = 'bob ' + $('.bob').css('color');

$('#result').text(
alice + '\n' + bob
);

$('#expected').text(
boblice + '\n' + bob
);

var elem1 = document.getElementById("alice");
alicestyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem1, null);

console.log(alicestyle);
```

```css
.alice {
  color:green;
}

.bob {
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='alice' class="alice" style="color:red">
test
</div>

<div id = 'bob' class="bob">
test
</div>

result:
<div id="result">

</div>

expected:
<div id="expected">

</div>

getComputedStyle:
<div id="computed">

</div>
```

---

Comment: You mean something like [**`getComputedStyle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)?

Comment: This link may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778814/read-css-property-from-stylesheet

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir No, getComputedStyle is including the style attribute.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach temporarily remove the `style` attribute / property (save the value somewhere), use `getComputedStyle` then re-apply the `style` attribute / property

Comment: I was weary about modifying the styles, in case something else changed (guess nth child stuff won't be affected, as it's a rule/selector), but it's at least a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can get the style directly from the stylesheets. But I think you can use below code for a workaround:

```
if( typeof( $('#alice').attr('style') ) != 'undefined' ) { 
   $('#alice').removeAttr('style'); 
   var aliceSheets = $('.alice').css('color');
   console.log(aliceSheets);
}
```

If you want to get the style only without changing the style of the element then you can add the `style` attribute back after reading the color.