# Listing all available CSS styles javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

let's imagine I've declared some styles (either directly on my html document or by external css file(s)):

```
<style>
.Red { background-color: red; }
.Green { background-color: green; }
.Blue { background-color: blue; }
</style>
```

In my javascript code I would like to list all available styles in Array or any other form

```
function getAvailableStyleNames(){
  return ["Red", "Green", "Blue"]; // Dummy code. the answer would go here...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe accessing `document.styleSheets`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets

Comment: For what purpose do you want this? Because you have so many combinations, some styles can be like ".Red .other div li:HOVER"...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/350573/1577562

Comment: This is a pretty good blog post on it: http://davidwalsh.name/add-rules-stylesheets

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the function that you want :

### CSS

```
.Red { background-color: red; }
.Green { background-color: green; }
.Blue { background-color: blue; }
```

### JS

```
function PrintRules() {
    var rules = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    var rulesDiv = document.getElementById("rules");
    for(var x=0;x<rules.length;x++) {
        rulesDiv.innerHTML += rules[x].selectorText + "<br />";
    }
}
```

### HTML

```
<input onclick="PrintRules()" type="button" value="Print Rules" /><br />
Rules:
<div id="rules"></div>
```

Comment: That's great! thank you very much!
Will it work in IE10 too? (I don't have a Windows PC here to test)
I guess I can iterate through styleSheets to get all styles also declared in external linked css files

Comment: Will it work in IE10 too? (I don't have a Windows PC here to test) I guess I can iterate through styleSheets to get all styles also declared in external linked css files

Comment: It's the same thing for me here ... You can host the page and test it here http://netrenderer.com/