# Retrieve CSS property value through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently i'd like to read out the background color of a css through javascript to update a canvas with the desired color. So far i get it to work by creating a *dummy* object within html that holds that css from which i can read it:

The CSS content:

```
.logmessage-debug {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #999999;
}

.logmessage-info {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #5cb85c;
}

.logmessage-warn {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #f0ad4e;
}

.logmessage-error {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d9534f;
}

.logmessage-fatal {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d955d9;
}
```

The HTML part:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<!-- The dummy objects allowing access to the css properties -->
<div id="debug" class="logmessage-debug"></div>
<div id="info" class="logmessage-info"></div>
<div id="warn" class="logmessage-warn"></div>
<div id="error" class="logmessage-error"></div>
<div id="fatal" class="logmessage-fatal"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    updateCanvas();
</script>
```

The JavaScript part:

```
function updateCanvas() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "api/myWebService",
        success: function (severityLevel) {
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = getSeverityColorFromStyle(severityLevel);
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.clientWidth, c.clientHeight);
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(updateCanvas, 2000);
        }
    })
}

function getSeverityColorFromStyle(styleName) {
    // Any other way to read the css background color
    // directly instead of asking the dummy object?
    return $("#" + styleName).css("background-color");
}
```

So far the above way works as expected and i can get out the desired colors i like. But I'm feeling uncomfortable by adding these dummy objects just to get access to the needed css values. Exists there any *direct* way to retrieve these values out of the css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it seems there exists no such simple way to access a css style like accessing an existing element within the document.

At the end i decided to take the answers from Paul and JBB and (hopefully) improved them a little bit. I iterate once over all available rules within all available style sheets and push the interesting things into my own cache object. Within the `getSeverityColorFromStyle()` method i then try to get the matching color out of it.

```
var logLevelColors;

function updateCanvas() {
    if(logLevelColors == undefined)
        initializeLogLevelColors();

    $.ajax({
        url: "api/myWebService",
        success: function (severityName) {
            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle = getSeverityColorFrom(severityName);
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.clientWidth, c.clientHeight);
        },
        complete: function() {
            setTimeout(updateCanvas, 2000);
        }
    })
}

function initializeLogLevelColors() {
    logLevelColors = new Object();
    var logMessageIdentifier = '.logmessage-';

    $.each(document.styleSheets, function (_, styleSheet) {
        $.each(styleSheet.rules, function (_, rule) {
            if (rule.selectorText.indexOf(logMessageIdentifier) == 0) {
                var logLevel = rule.selectorText.substring(logMessageIdentifier.length);
                var color = rule.style.backgroundColor;

                logLevelColors[logLevel] = color;
            }
        })
    })
}
function getSeverityColorFrom(severityName) {
    var undefinedColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00)';

    if (logLevelColors == undefined)
        return undefinedColor;

    return logLevelColors[severityName]
           || undefinedColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function that loops through all the stylesheets/rules on your page and tries to match it

```
function getStyle(className) {
var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules
for(var x=0;x<classes.length;x++) {
    if(classes[x].selectorText==className) {
            return (classes[x].cssText) ? classes[x].cssText : classes[x].style.cssText;
        }
    }
}
```

See this previous post for more detail [How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)

Comment: I already seen that question at SO and i simply find a little bit dumb to iterate through all this stuff on myself. I just thought there exists a *better way* instead of manual looping.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the position of the **[*Rule*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleRule)** or the **[*Sheet*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet)** it is in, you can easily get it via the related *CSSStyleSheet*, e.g.

```html
<style id="foo">/* etc */</style>
```

Then

```js
function getSeverityColorFromStyle(kwd) {
    var i, rules = document.getElementById('foo').sheet.rules;
    kwd = '.logmessage-' + kwd;
    for (i = rules.length; i--;) // find in sheet's rules
        if (rules[i].selectorText.indexOf(kwd) !== -1) // found
            return rules[i].style.backgroundColor;
    return '';
}
```

Accessing the `style` of a *CSSStyleRule* enables you to let the browser parse the *cssText*.

If you don't know the sheet, you may want to do another loop over [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets)

Comment: This can be further optimised if you cache the _HTMLStyleElement_ (if applicable) or the rule's indices

Answer (score 0):

```
var theColor = $('.class').css('background-color');
```

Comment: Will this work if there are no _Nodes_ in the _#document_ which match `.class`, but there is the _CSS_ rule for it?

Comment: I don't think so, because it doesn't exist yet as an element in the dom

Comment: -1: This only works if the dummy objects are created within the html page. If you remove them you'll get an "undefined".

Comment: @AlienArrays: That either does not work if you remove the dummy objects from the html.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the css class directly to canvas?

Something like: `<canvas id="myCanvas" class="error"></canvas>`, and then you could actually get the computed style of the canvas, and update the elements inside.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"), styles = getComputedStyle(canvas);

//log the properties
console.log(styles.color, styles.backgroundColor);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work. I simplified the example but in the real scenario i get through the web api call a list of severity levels which i have to visualize within the canvas and not only a single value. So this does not work.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var myText = document.getElementById("text");
   alert(myText.style.display);
   alert(myText.style.color);
   ...etc
</script>
```

Comment: -1: There is no element (or at least this is what i like to avoid) which i could retrieve by Id.