# How to get style of a div from javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, styles

Iam new to javascript, I have given style for a div by using javascript in one js file and i want to get that style from another js file. how it is possible??
when i used 
    `var height= $("#searchComment").css("height");` 
and on alerting the result it is get like 'undefined'.
if this style is given in html it returns correctly. 
    test1.js and test2.js are included in index.html
In test1.js ihave given styling to a div of id 'searchComment'

```
$( "#parentDiv").append("<div class='ui-li-desc' id='searchComment' style='height:50px; width:40 px'></div>");

and in another js file test2.js i want to get the style of div of id 'searchComment'.
how can i get this style?? please help me.
Thank you
```

Comment: No idea at all what you're asking.

Comment: Can you please reformulate your question, giving also a better example. Also, trying to anwser you problem as I understant it, javascript supports global variables which are accesible among all the files.

Comment: Try to elaborate with what you doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change of any elements style from any file, But the standard practice is to add class instead of changing style of an element. To add class you can use .addClass('new-class') jQuery function. And put all your style for new class in separate CSS file. And if you just want to add style anyway without caring about standard, then you can use .css jquery function.

```
$(".number").css({
  'attribute1': value,
  'attribute2': value,
});
```

Answer (score 3):

use jquery selector and then change css:

```
   $('.number').css({'font-size': '12px', 'text-align': 'left'});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to give ID for that div by using the id you can get it from other JS

Limitation :

```
Both js should be using in that HTML file.

Before using id of <div> you have to create that div
```

Ex :

test1.js

```
$("#commentList").append(<div class='number' id="mydiv" style='font-size: 18px; 
text-align: justify; direction: rtl; float: right; width: 12%; padding-top:75px;'>
   some Variable</div>);
```

test2.js

```
document.getElementById("mydiv").style;
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you want the description of the css class use. refer the post

```
function getStyleRules(className) {
    var class = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    for (var x = 0; x < class.length; x++) {
        if (class[x].selectorText == className) {
            (class[x].cssText) ? alert(class[x].cssText) : alert(classes[x].style.cssText);
        }
    }
}
getStyleRules('.YourClassName');
```

[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)