# Can't get width property with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

My idea is when I click on the button, the `div#x` will lose 1% of width. Here is my code:

```js
document.querySelector('#a').onclick = function() {
    var
        lost = document.querySelector('#x').style.width,
        lost = lost.slice(0, -1);
    lost = Number(lost);
    lost -= 1;
    document.querySelector('#x').style.width = lost + '%';
}
```

```css
nav#control {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 50px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%
}

.knob {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 40px; height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer
}

#b {
    position: relative;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    margin: 0 10px;
    height: 30px
}
#x {
    position: absolute;
    background: #4C8EFA;
    width: 100%; height: 30px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    z-index: 2
}
#c {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav id='control'>
    <section id='a' class='knob'><img src='x.png'/></section>
    <section id='b'>
        <div id='x'></div>
        <div id='c'>background</div>
    </section>
    <section id='d' class='knob'><img src='x.png'/></section>
</nav>
```

The blue bar (`div#x`) is supposed to be shorter 1% every time I click on the left button (`section#a`). I have check so many times but I still don't know what problem with my code. I did change some code and I think that problem is in this line `lost = document.querySelector('#x').style.width` because it seems like it doesn't return any value which is supposed to gimme `100%` width of `div#x`

Comment: What is `catchID()`?

Comment: Unfortunately, the `style.width` does not give you the percentage that is coming from the CSS.

Comment: The `.style` object only has styles that are applied directly on the element. Styles implied by CSS rules won't be available there.

Comment: @Blazemonger My bad, catchID() is just my own function to get ID element. I have fix the right code.

Comment: @jwatts1980 I did try on http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_width.asp and it working pretty well with other HTML code.

Comment: @Pointy I also add it directly on the #x but it won't work. And I think there are no diffirent betwen directly insert or insert in independence file.

Comment: `element.style` refers to the `style` attribute of the HTML element. If the width is set in the style attribute like `style="width:100%;"` then `element.style.width` will equal `100%`. But when the element's style is being set in the CSS, `element.style.width` will be empty or null.

Comment: @jwatts1980 Thanks, I got it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```js
var x = document.querySelector('#x');
var initialWidth = x.clientWidth;

window.onresize = function() {
  //Be careful about calculating too many things in the resize handler!
  //This isn't that intensive, so it shouldn't matter, but look into "debouncing" if you have things like this elsewhere
  initialWidth = x.clientWidth;
};

document.getElementById("a").onclick = function() {
  x.style.width = x.clientWidth - (initialWidth * 0.01) + "px";
};
```

```css
nav#control {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #FFF;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%
}
.knob {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer
}
#b {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: #EFEFEF;
  margin: 0 10px;
  height: 30px
}
#x {
  position: absolute;
  background: #4C8EFA;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  z-index: 2
}
#c {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<nav id='control'>
  <section id='a' class='knob'>
    <img src='x.png' />
  </section>
  <section id='b'>
    <div id='x'></div>
    <div id='c'>background</div>
  </section>
  <section id='d' class='knob'>
    <img src='x.png' />
  </section>
</nav>
```

This uses `clientWidth` to get the real width of the element (in terms of pixels), takes 1% off that number, then reset the number back to pixels again.

Explanation:

In your original code, you were trying to access `style.width` of `#x`.  Since this is a percentage, and not a static value, this will actually return nothing.  Luckily, we can get the rendered width of the element with Javascript's `clientWidth` property.  Using this, we can find the real size of the bar, and calculate the new values from that.

It also might be possible to directly inject the CSS with [insertRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) - but I don't see any problems with the `clientWidth` solution.

**EDIT: Use @jwatts1980's solution from the comments: http://jsfiddle.net/a9okwLd1/1/**

Comment: The only caveat is that by multiplying by 99% every time it will never be fully reduced.

Comment: @jwatts1980 Good point - I've updated my answer, this should fix it.

Comment: Oh, can you gimme some explanation, plz?

Comment: @ScottKaye That is better, but it does not account for the size of the document changing. I think the `var` should hold the current percentage. Then you can multiply that by the `clientWidth`.

Comment: @jwatts1980 I tried to implement my CSS `insertRule` suggestion; turns out it's harder than it seems to [find the right selector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/324533/382456) - a `window.resize` handler is clunky, but it seems to work.  If you can figure out a better way to do this, I'd love to take a look though!

Comment: I see, you should post that as an answer then, it's far better than the answers here.

Comment: @ScottKaye Heh heh, no that's fine. You have this one. I made that previous comment, then it clicked: I'm so used to updating the size by pixels on HTML elements that I forgot that you can use `%` and even `em` when you're setting the `element.style.width`.

Comment: Thank you so much, jwatts and Scott Kaye. I'm very appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1):

This bit is kinda messy:

```
catchID('a').onclick = function() {
    var
        lost = document.querySelector('#x').style.width,
        lost = lost.slice(0, -1);
    lost = Number(lost);
    lost -= 1;
    document.querySelector('#x').style.width = lost + '%';
}
```

Also, what is `catchID()`?

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('a.knob').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById('x');
    elem.offsetWidth = .99 * elem.offsetWidth;
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like so:

```
var w=document.getElementById("x").offsetWidth,
r=parseInt(w*.01);
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click",function(){
    w-=r;
    document.getElementById("x").style.width=w+"px";
},0);
```