# Get CSS class definition from chrome developer tools console

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to programatically retrieve a set of CSS class definitions from chrome developer tools. In effect similar to what is displayed in styles tab in the right hand side. The input needs to be a class name and the output should be all the styles defined in it.

I'm aware of getComputedStyle DOM method, but this doesn't separate into separate classes which I need.

Comment: This approach worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27527462/1023562, it lets you invoke the JS code in Chrome console like this: `console.log(getStyle('#heder_logo a'));` and get results like this: `#heder_logo a { width: 200px; height: 114px; display: block; }`. I did have issues with some CSS files which were not on the same domain (they were pulled from CDN), but there are variety of proposals there, so some should work for you.

Comment: thanks, that looks very promising. you want to add this as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one?

Comment: Glad to hear that, I have added the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This approach worked for me ([stackoverflow.com/a/27527462/1023562](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27527462/1023562)):

```
 /**
     * Gets styles by a classname
     * 
     * @notice The className must be 1:1 the same as in the CSS
     * @param string className_
     */
    function getStyle(className_) {
    var styleSheets = window.document.styleSheets;
    var styleSheetsLength = styleSheets.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < styleSheetsLength; i++){
        var classes = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;
        var classesLength = classes.length;
        for (var x = 0; x < classesLength; x++) {
            if (classes[x].selectorText == className_) {
                var ret;
                if(classes[x].cssText){
                    ret = classes[x].cssText;
                } else {
                    ret = classes[x].style.cssText;
                }
                if(ret.indexOf(classes[x].selectorText) == -1){
                    ret = classes[x].selectorText + "{" + ret + "}";
                }
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It lets you invoke the `javascript` code in Chrome console like this:

```
console.log(getStyle('#heder_logo a'));
```

and get results like this:

```
> #heder_logo a { width: 200px; height: 114px; display: block; }.
```

I did have issues with some CSS files which were not on the same domain (they were pulled from CDN), but there are variety of proposals in that thread, so some should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

Have adapted Ivan's answer in order to get a more complete result. This method will also return styles where the class is part for the selector

```
//Get all styles where the provided class is involved
//Input parameters should be css selector such as .myClass or #m
//returned as an array of tuples {selectorText:"", styleDefinition:""}
function getStyleWithCSSSelector(cssSelector) {
    var styleSheets = window.document.styleSheets;
    var styleSheetsLength = styleSheets.length;
    var arStylesWithCSSSelector = [];

    //in order to not find class which has the current name as prefix
    var arValidCharsAfterCssSelector = [" ", ".", ",", "#",">","+",":","["];

    //loop through all the stylessheets in the bor
    for(var i = 0; i < styleSheetsLength; i++){
        var classes = styleSheets[i].rules || styleSheets[i].cssRules;
        var classesLength = classes.length;
        for (var x = 0; x < classesLength; x++) {
            //check for any reference to the class in the selector string
            if(typeof classes[x].selectorText != "undefined"){
                var matchClass = false;

                if(classes[x].selectorText === cssSelector){//exact match
                    matchClass=true;
                }else {//check for it as part of the selector string
                    //TODO: Optimize with regexp
                    for (var j=0;j<arValidCharsAfterCssSelector.length; j++){
                        var cssSelectorWithNextChar = cssSelector+ arValidCharsAfterCssSelector[j];

                        if(classes[x].selectorText.indexOf(cssSelectorWithNextChar)!=-1){
                            matchClass=true;
                            //break out of for-loop
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if(matchClass === true){
                    //console.log("Found "+ cssSelectorWithNextChar + " in css class definition " + classes[x].selectorText);
                    var styleDefinition;
                    if(classes[x].cssText){
                        styleDefinition = classes[x].cssText;
                    } else {
                        styleDefinition = classes[x].style.cssText;
                    }
                    if(styleDefinition.indexOf(classes[x].selectorText) == -1){
                        styleDefinition = classes[x].selectorText + "{" + styleDefinition + "}";
                    }
                    arStylesWithCSSSelector.push({"selectorText":classes[x].selectorText, "styleDefinition":styleDefinition});
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(arStylesWithCSSSelector.length==0) {
        return null;
    }else {
        return arStylesWithCSSSelector;    
    }
}
```

In addition, I've made a function which collects the css style definitions to the sub-tree of a root node your provide (through a jquery selector).

```
function getAllCSSClassDefinitionsForSubtree(selectorOfRootElement){
    //stack in which elements are pushed and poped from
    var arStackElements = [];
    //dictionary for checking already added css class definitions
    var existingClassDefinitions = {}

    //use jquery for selecting root element
    var rootElement = $(selectorOfRootElement)[0];
    //string with the complete CSS output
    var cssString = "";

    console.log("Fetching all classes used in sub tree of " +selectorOfRootElement);
    arStackElements.push(rootElement);
    var currentElement;

    while(currentElement = arStackElements.pop()){
        currentElement = $(currentElement);
        console.log("Processing element " + currentElement.attr("id"));

        //Look at class attribute of element 
        var classesString = currentElement.attr("class");
        if(typeof classesString != 'undefined'){
            var arClasses = classesString.split(" ");

            //for each class in the current element
            for(var i=0; i< arClasses.length; i++){

                //fetch the CSS Styles for a single class. Need to append the . char to indicate its a class
                var arStylesWithCSSSelector = getStyleWithCSSSelector("."+arClasses[i]);
                console.log("Processing class "+ arClasses[i]);

                if(arStylesWithCSSSelector != null){
                    //console.log("Found "+ arStylesWithCSSSelector.length + " CSS style definitions for class " +arClasses[i]);
                    //append all found styles to the cssString
                    for(var j=0; j< arStylesWithCSSSelector.length; j++){
                        var tupleStyleWithCSSSelector = arStylesWithCSSSelector[j];

                        //check if it has already been added
                        if(typeof existingClassDefinitions[tupleStyleWithCSSSelector.selectorText] === "undefined"){
                            //console.log("Adding " + tupleStyleWithCSSSelector.styleDefinition);
                            cssString+= tupleStyleWithCSSSelector.styleDefinition;
                            existingClassDefinitions[tupleStyleWithCSSSelector.selectorText] = true;
                        }else {
                            //console.log("Already added " + tupleStyleWithCSSSelector.styleDefinition);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //push all child elments to stack
        if(currentElement.children().length>0){
            arStackElements= arStackElements.concat(currentElement.children().toArray());
        }
    }

    console.log("Found " + Object.keys(existingClassDefinitions).length + " CSS class definitions");
    return cssString;
}
```

Note that if a class is defined several times with the same selector, the above function will only pick up the first.

Answer (score 0):

Python script to search css file for a word once found read what is inbetween the curly braces. Quick and dirty way**

Comment: Thanks, but the css classes may be defined in multiple different files which I may not have access to on the file system (and I dont't really want to fetch the files over http and search)