# Injecting CSS into directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a directive and I want to inject some CSS for that directive.

As there could be multiple directives in the same page, I want to avoid injecting that CSS multiple times. What method should I use? `.run`? `.config`?

Also, how exactly would I inject that CSS?

For the sake of this example, let's say that I just want to inject `.my-item { background: blue; }`

Comment: Is it possible that you confuse directives with elements (directive = JavaScript, element = HTML)? What exactly do you mean by _"inject some CSS for that directive"_?

Comment: @zeroflagL "directive" == angular directive. "Inject some CSS for that directive" == Some CSS styling generated with javascript, instead of fetching a `.css` file.

Comment: The place to inject CSS is the directive function. It only depends on your code if CSS is injected multiple times or not.

Comment: @zeroflagL the `.directive` function will run once for each directive coincidence in the HTML code, right? (two `<my-directive></my-directive>` elements will trigger the `.directive` function twice). What I'm asking is if `.run` or `.config` will be ran once, thus allowing me to avoid checking if the styles were already injected.

Comment: The directive function runs exactly once. The compile, link etc. functions run once per element.

Comment: I am confused. I always lived under the assumption that `run()` and `config()` blocks were a feature of angular modules and not applicable to directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some generated CSS in angular by doing the following:

```
angular.element(document).find('head').prepend('<style type="text/css">.my-item { background: blue; }</style>');
```

To make sure that this isn't injected multiple times, you could create a  service `CssSvc` which can keep track of whether the generated CSS has been injected yet or not.

```
app.service('CssSvc', function () {
    var svc = this;

    // keep track if injected
    svc.injected = false;

});
```

Then you can inject the service in to your directive and only run the above code if it has not been run already.

```
if(!CssSvc.injected) {
    angular.element(document).find('head').prepend('<style type="text/css">.my-item { background: blue; }</style>');
    CssSvc.injected = true;
}
```

Comment: One more thing. Is there a way I can fetch the definition of a css class? (Not by searching for an item in the DOM that has been assigned that class, but the class itself)

Comment: There's a few techniques in the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript