# How to change color of Dygraph Series via CSS

Tags: css, colors, dygraphs

I know how to change the color of a Dygraph Series using the Dygraph options:

Example:

```
new Dygraph(el, data, {
color: 'blue'
});
```

But I don't know how (or if it's possible) to define the color of a series via CSS:

Psuedo Example:

```
#dygraph-series-1 {
color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the css rules via javascript like so:
[How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)

then you can initialize the graph with these rules:

```
var myColor = readCssRule('myColor');

new Dygraph(el, data, {
color: myColor
});
```