# How to get a list of images urls in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been working on creating my first chrome extension. I have done several of the sample extensions that can be found at https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

How do I make an extension that will return a list of the src of all of the images on an open tab in chrome?

I know the basics in javascript, so I would like to create the extension with that language. This is not like the other in that I would like to get the full url and I would like to use simple javascript instead of trying to use json which I don't know.

Here is my manifest.json file

```
{
"name": "Getting Started",
"description": "Get The sources of the images",
"version": "2.0",
"permissions":[
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
],
"browser_action":{
    "default_title": "Image Source",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
},
"content_scripts":[
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
],
"manifest_version": 2 
}
```

And here is my content.js file

```
var len = document.images.length;
var imgs = document.images;
var sources = "";
for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
     sources = sources + imgs[i].src + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("sources").innerHTML = sources;
/*if (len > 0){
    alert(len + " images were found on page");
}
else{
    alert("No images were found on page");
}*/ // Used these to see if there were any images on the page
```

And finally my popup.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Awesome extension</title>
    <script src="content.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="sources">There might be images here</p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No one is going to do the work for you. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I would suggest that you read the [Chrome extension architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)  (and perhaps work through reading the pages linked from there). It has overall architecture information which should help your understanding of how things are generally organized/done.

Comment: I solved this problem   https://stackoverflow.com/a/58744482/1919821

Answer (score 1):

To get the images from the active tab when your extension is clicked you can inject your content script using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) instead of having a content_scripts entry in the manifest.json and use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get an array of the images' sources:

**popup.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Awesome extension</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="sources">There might be images here</p>    
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
var callback = function (results) {
    // ToDo: Do something with the image urls (found in results[0])

    document.body.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i in results[0]) {
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = results[0][i];

        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
};

chrome.tabs.query({ // Get active tab
    active: true,
    currentWindow: true
}, function (tabs) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {
        code: 'Array.prototype.map.call(document.images, function (i) { return i.src; });'
    }, callback);
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Getting Started",
    "description": "Get The sources of the images",
    "version": "2.0",
    "permissions":[
        "activeTab",
        "tabs"
    ],
    "browser_action":{
        "default_title": "Image Source",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2 
}
```