# How to get elements width by classname using javascript for loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i tested it's will be alert `blank value` and `30px` 
I want to get alert `400px` and `30px` How can i do ?

```css
.div_cover_threads_image{
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_cover_threads_image">
test
</div>

<div class="div_cover_threads_image" style="width: 30px;">
test
</div>


<script>     
var div_cover_threads_image_Elem = document.getElementsByClassName('div_cover_threads_image');
for(var i=0, len=div_cover_threads_image_Elem.length; i<len; i++)
{
   alert(div_cover_threads_image_Elem[i].style.width);
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)

Comment: You've created some confusion by tagging `jQuery` but using vanilla `javascript` in your snippet.  Which do you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've tagged jQuery, this will return the elements width even if no width was explicitly defined:

```css
.div_cover_threads_image{
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div_cover_threads_image">
test
</div>

<div class="div_cover_threads_image" style="width: 30px;">
test
</div>


<script>     
var div_cover_threads_image_Elem = document.getElementsByClassName('div_cover_threads_image');
for(var i=0, len=div_cover_threads_image_Elem.length; i<len; i++)
{
   alert($(div_cover_threads_image_Elem[i]).width());
}  
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You used `Element.style` on the second `div` which means inline style. For the first one you need to use `window.getComputedStyle(Element,[, pseudoElt])` in order to get all styles of it.

Extract the width by:

```
var width=window.getComputedStyle(Element,null).getPropertyValue('width');
```

The returned value will be something like `400px`. If you wish to use the numeric value without unit, try `parseFloat`.

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName( 'div_cover_threads_image' );
for(var i=0, len=els.length; i<len; i++)
{
    var computed = getComputedStyle( els[i], null );
    alert( computed.getPropertyValue( 'width' ) );
}
```

If you use jQuery, things will be more simple. Just `$('.div_cover_threads_image').width();`

Answer (score 0):

From jquery,

```
.div_cover_threads_image{
  width: 400px;
}

<div class="div_cover_threads_image">
test
</div>

<div class="div_cover_threads_image" style="width: 30px;">
test
</div>


<script>     
$( ".div_cover_threads_image" ).each(function() {
  alert($( this ).width());
});
</script>
```