# Sum up values of inline styles with css styles

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a margin of an element set in the .scss file of my React component:

```
.element {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

I want to sum up this value with a value set to margin in inline styles:

```
<div className={scss.element} style={{ margin: 10px }}>Whatever</div>
```

**The end result should be:** `margin: 30px`

Comment: this can't be done using css thus, you could use javascript, otherwise you could put the end value you want i.e. `style={{ margin: 30px }}` inline style which will override the `margin` value coming from `.scss`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is get both the CSS files computed style and the inline style and add them both together

I used the following function to get the CSS files style:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27527462/5814976

(Thanks Dude! https://stackoverflow.com/users/3894981/dude)

`var cssElm = getStyle('.element'),
        cssVal = cssElm.split('margin:')[1].split(';')[0],`

then used the vanilla `blah.style` to retrieve the inline style (this only fetched the highest ranking style so if you had an `!important` tag in your CSS file it would just get that again and the end result would be 40px).

`inlineVal = elm[0].style.margin,`

Then we clean up both of the strings we retrieved (to remove any units that have applied (em, px etc) and then add them together:

`totalVal = parseInt(cssVal.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")) + parseInt(inlineVal.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));`

and lastly reapplied the style to the original element.

`elm[0].style.margin = totalVal + 'px';`

you can see a working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mdhkxhhd/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function myfns() {

  var x = document.getElementById("mytxt").value

  document.getElementById("p2").style.margin = x + "px";

}
```

```html
<div id="p2" className="scss.element" style=" margin: 10px ">Whatever</div>
<input type="number" id="mytxt" />
<button onclick="myfns()">Set Margin</button>
```

Comment: The value of an inline style is variable. So setting fixed value of 30px won't do the trick.

Comment: @Eduard I change the answer try it

Answer (score 0):

try this:
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Micio/h70y8mwo/)

```
var marginStyle=parseInt(document.getElementById("element").style.margin) ;


var marginCss=parseInt($(".element").css("margin"));

var sum=marginStyle+marginCss;
$("p").html( 'Style margin '+marginStyle+'<br> Css margin '+marginCss +'<br>sum '+sum);

$(".element").css("cssText", "margin:"+sum+"px !important;");
```