# How could we find the styleSheets of a page which is insided any iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How could we find the styleSheets of a page which is inside any iframe.

```
<iframe id="#iframe" src="view_page.php" 
style="transition: none 0s ease 0s;" width="750" height="899"></iframe>

console.log(document.styleSheets);
```

The above thing will work if page is loaded in browser without iframe.
document.styleSheets will give an array of StyleSheets, included in file. But, it doesn't work when page is inside iframe.

Comment: Is the iframe from the same origin? because if it's not you will be limited by the same origin policy

Comment: yes, it's from the same origin.

Comment: try this document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].contentDocument.head

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript) , 
check this solution, but this is for page not for page inside iframe

Comment: @SaiyamGambhir  i got the answer for my question.

document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].contentDocument.styleSheets

This will tell me all external stylesheets included in iframe page.

Comment: @MithileshKumar hope I helped you.