# How to get div height with min-height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the height prop of a div in jQuery.
That's really simple :

```
$("#mydiv").css("height");
```

That's right. But if the div have a min-height superior of the height, this code will return the min-height. How can I force it to give me the height ?

Example :

```js
$("#result").html($("#mydiv").css("height"));
```

```css
#mydiv{
  width : 100px;
  height : 10px;
  min-height : 80px;
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<div id="result"></div>
In this example, how can I get "10px" ?
```

Comment: Height of element is `80px` as you can see in **browser inspect**

Comment: Hi @Mohammad. Sure, but how can i get the "height" style value (here 10px) ?

Comment: No way to get it. js can only reads the DOM objects, this is the actual value of your element height property.

Comment: Hi @vaso123. Argh ! ^^ thx (I'll wait 5 min and put it as solved).

Comment: What vaso123 said, javascript takes direct elements height, not what written in a height thing.

Comment: As you mentioned min-height is `80px` it will override the height property if it less than. In your example height is `10px`.

Comment: And if it's not in a stylesheet page but int the stye attr ? (<div style="height:10px;background:red;"></div>

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `min-height` of element to `auto` and get `height` property of it. Then return `min-height` to first value.

```js
var minHeight = $("#mydiv").css("min-height");
$("#mydiv").css("min-height", "auto");
console.log($("#mydiv").height());
$("#mydiv").css("min-height", minHeight);
```

```css
#mydiv{
  width : 100px;
  height : 10px;
  min-height : 80px;
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thx, can be a cood idea, sound a little bit like a hack but can be ok ;)

Answer (score 0):

As you are keeping the min-height to 80px which is greater than 10px(height).

Your div will be 80px all the time.

As you can see in the below example I have kept height to 100px and see it's  it's height getting 100px not 80px as height is greater then min height.

```js
$("#result").html($("#mydiv").css("height"));
```

```css
#mydiv{
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  min-height : 80px;
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv"></div>





<div id="result"></div>
In this example, how can I get "10px" ?
```

So, if you want ur div to be 10px tall then either remove min-height or set min-height value to be samller than 10px.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is only when min-height is > to height (I need this condition ^^)

Answer (score 0):

Although Mohammed's answer is the best way, another way is to add a child and set its height to 'inherit' and read the 'height' property from the child.

```js
var source = $("#mydiv");
var sourceHeight = source.append('<div></div>').find('div').css('height', 'inherit').css('height');
console.log('height of source is '+sourceHeight);
source.find('div').remove(); //make sure to remove it
```

```css
#mydiv{
  width : 100px;
  height : 10px;
  min-height : 80px;
  background : red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv" style=""></div>
```