# Issue getting CSS calc width with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-calc

I need to make a square element that is based off of the width of the screen. To set the height the same as the width, I tried using JS, but it seems to get it slightly wrong. Here is an example

```js
var square = document.getElementById('square');
square.style.height = square.clientWidth + 'px';
```

```css
#square {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc(20vw - 16px);
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">Element</div>
```

The blue "square" above is not square. Could any explain why? Instead of `clientWidth`, I've tried `scrollWidth` and `offsetWidth` with similar results. I haven't gotten `style.width` to give out a correct number either.

Even if you inspect, on Chrome, the blue square you get a number for the height and width that are close but still very different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two issues. First you need to consider the padding, so add `box-sizing:border-box` then you defined the width using `vw` unit, so you will have a sqaure **only** when you open the page the first time and **never** resize the browser.

```js
var square = document.getElementById('square');
square.style.height = square.clientWidth + 'px';
```

```css
#square {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc(20vw - 16px);
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">Element</div>
```

if you want a square that stay on window resize you need to use the same specified value and not the computed value in pixel ([How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/324486/8620333))

Or change the value on resize:

```js
var square = document.getElementById('square');
square.style.height = square.clientWidth + 'px';

window.onresize=function() {
  square.style.height = square.clientWidth + 'px';
};
```

```css
#square {
  background-color: blue;
  width: calc(20vw - 16px);
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">Element</div>
```

---

As a side note you can consider CSS variable to specify the same value only once or check this : [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1495407/8620333)

```css
#square {
  --v:calc(20vw - 16px);
  background-color: blue;
  width: var(--v);
  height: var(--v);
  padding: 8px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">Element</div>
```

Comment: Do you need to use js for that ?

Comment: @wadie not, but I am answering the question *why*

Comment: Sure, just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the same calc for the height

```
width: calc(20vw - 16px);
height: calc(20vw - 16px);
```