# Is it possible to read CSS class attribute value before the class is added to an HTML Element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to read a CSS class attribute value before the class is added to an HTML element using javascript?

```
 .myclass {
    color: #00aa00;
  }
```

For example, how can I read the "color" attribute value of "myclass" before the "myclass" added to an HTML element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/324533/505002

Comment: Would that be when you the browser is creating the element (e.g. when it's parsing the body) or like whenever you modify the element through JS?