# How can I pass only the styles of an element to another element?

Tags: javascript, css

I was trying to pass the CSS of a element to another element, I wrote a function (demo included):

```js
extendcss = (el1, el2) => {
     if(typeof(el1) == 'object' && typeof(el2) == 'object'){
     Array.prototype.slice.call(el1.attributes).forEach(function (item) {
       el2.setAttribute(item.name, item.value);
     });
   }
   else{
     Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelector(el1).attributes).forEach(function (item) {
       document.querySelector(el2).setAttribute(item.name, item.value);
     });
   }
   }
 $('button').click(()=>{
 extendcss('#parent', '#child');
 });
```

```css
#parent{
color: white;
background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="parent">Parent</h1>
<h1 id="child">Child</h1>
<button>DO</button>
```

The problem is that, when the method is called, all the attributes of the first element, like id, class, style, and other things get included and added to second element. I haven't figured out how to pass the style only to the second element.

Please help me in passing **only style of the element** from the element.

Comment: The `style` object only contains style information that's directly on the elements; that is, the contents of the `style` attribute itself. CSS rules have no effect on that; you have to use `.getComputedStyle()`

Comment: but the `.getComputedStyle()` also returns all the unnecessary and undefined  things. I don't want that

Comment: The most usable/easy way to do this is create a class and share with any elements that you want.

Comment: No, @ViniciusDutra, this is not what I wanted

Comment: If you don't want to share `getComputedStyle` nor share a class, then you're either needlessly complicating the *solution* or perhaps *the requirement*. This seems a bit like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  - can you say what are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @ObnoxiousNerd, if you want really to do this, i suggest you to do what aready said before, use .getComputedStyle(), but with a virtual element that implement the rules that you want, for this, you can use a class

Comment: Could you just comment a way to do that, @ViniciusDutra

Comment: look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript at the first answer the getStyle function

Comment: I'd probably go for second answer, that worked. Thanks, user