# Detecting change in sticky CSS object with jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, position, sticky

Is it possible with jQuery or JS to detect when an element has become "stuck", from the css property, position: sticky?

I've attached a screenshot of the interface that I am trying to recreate.

If you look at the attached image, basically, when you scroll down the page, the purple tiles become "stuck", using the CSS property `position: sticky`.

When you scroll, I want it so that the correct letter in the alphabetical list at the top (in the light blue bar), becomes highlighted.

So essentially, I need to figure out a way to detect which tile is currently stuck to the top. I am asking if there is a jquery or javascript event to detect this.

Something like:

```
if ($("#a-tile").is(":sticky")) {
    $(".alphabet-nav-link[data-rel-id='a']").addClass("active");
}
```

Naturally, that doesn't work, and various Google searches have not shown much by way of results.

Is anybody aware of a way to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please read how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please provide a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your issue on what have you tried and issues in `code` to get help from someone. There is a high chance you question will be closed and down-voted.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping - I restructured the question and added an image to better illustrate what I am attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Aardvarks and anteaters are different animals. Also, there should be some other property (like a class) on the element that determines that it's sticky. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript can help you out, but it should be a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's css method. Eg: `$('#a-tile').css('position')`