# Get all styles from any element with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I working in some project.

I need get all classes with styles of any html element

***Example***

**Element:**

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-transparent-white font-weight-bold py-3 px-6 mr-2">
    Agregar Medicamento
</a>
```

Code JS

```
var classes = e.target.className.split(' ');

console.log(classes);
```

**Result:**

`["btn", "btn-transparent-white", "font-weight-bold", "py-3", "px-6", "mr-2"]`

With my code I can get styles of classes

```css
.btn
transition: color 0.15s ease 0s, background-color 0.15s ease 0s, border-color 0.15s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease 0s;

.font-weight-bold
font-weight: 500 !important;

.py-3
padding-bottom: 0.75rem !important;

.px-6
padding-left: 1.5rem !important;

.btn-transparent-white
undefined
```

But I have a problem with combined styles for example

`.btn.btn-white-transparent`

Any idea how I can to search any coincidences of element?

**Edited:**

Thanks for you anwers but I can search single classes , my problem is when I want to search .btn-white-transparent. this is a combined style,

I want to seach `.btn-white-transparent` and the anwer will be ***`.btn.btn-white-transparent { color:#FFF}`***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)

Comment: FYI if you want all the classes, just use `e.target.classList`.

Comment: That helps to search for an element for example .btn, my problem is when I want to search for .btn-white-transparent as it does not exist alone, it is combined with another, like this .btn.btn-white-transparent and I don't know how to search for it