# Is it possible to access cssRules in Node JS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I am attempting to modify CSS as part of a Node JS build process, but most of what I can find online refers to doing this in the DOM with Javascript. Is it possible to read a file in Node and access the equivalent of document.stylesheet or the cssRules property or is this a DOM-only concept and I need to stick with string replacement to modify these CSS rules/properties?

For reference here is the browser-based answer to the problem I'm trying to solve: [How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript)

Comment: You can do it by doing the same sort of text replacement on it that people [often do with Javascript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-replace). What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why are you modifying styles at *build* time?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to implement the CSSOM in nodejs. Are you looking for a library that has already done it?

Comment: Yep that was what I was looking for, I think the JSDOM is going to do the trick from the answer below but thanks for responding.

Comment: Actually @Bergi JSDOM seems designed for HTML much moreso than CSS so if you have a recommendation for another library I'd love to check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's nothing bad to manipulate CSS with DOM, use for that: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom

For manipulate CSS directly you could parse it into AST:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-tree

> CSSTree is a tool set for CSS: fast detailed parser (CSS → AST), walker (AST traversal), generator (AST → CSS) and lexer (validation and matching) based on specs and browser implementations. The main goal is to be efficient and W3C spec compliant, with focus on CSS analyzing and source-to-source transforming tasks.