# dynamically retieve style from css with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a function where I can pass in a selector name and a property and get back the css rule that matches.
for example, If I had a css class that is called "hedgehog" that applies a background color "blue", I want to call getCssTheme("hedgehog", "backgroundColor") and get back "blue".

I think I got close based on [How do you read CSS rule values with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324486/how-do-you-read-css-rule-values-with-javascript) and http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/cssrule.shtml

I have :

```
function getCssTheme(element, property) {
   var classes = document.styleSheets[1].cssRules;
   for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {        
      if (classes[x].selectorText == element) {
         var rules = classes[x].cssText || classes[x].style.cssText
         for (var y = 0; y < rules.length; y++){
            if (/*verify that the y-th property is the specified one*/) { 
              return rules[y];
            }
         }
      }         
   }
}
```

I left out the check on the final if, because I don't know how to reference the property name, and I'm only guessing the return will respond right.

Anybody know the way to reference the property name? (Is this type of code even possible?)

Comment: If you `console.log(rules[y])` what do you get?

Comment: I get console.log(rules) [no in the loop] returns: ".checkedTask { background-color: rgb(136, 136, 136); color: white; }";
console.log(rules[y]) returns the same thing, but the one character at a time. => it will log "." and then "c" "h" "e" etc.

Comment: This shows that your second loop is not necessary since it is processing every character of the string contained in `rules`. If you want to continue down this path you will need to find it create a CSS parser and parse the string contained in `rules`

Answer (score 1):

Extracting the value of CSS Property directly from Stylesheet doesn't seem to be the right thing to do. I say this because the value of a property might change when multiple CSS files work together to bring the final value of any class's property.

Consider the case where StyleSheetA, and StyleSheetB both have `sample-class`, and one sets `font-size` to `2em` while the other sets it to `3em`. In this case which value do you want? Do you know which one will be applied on any element, what if one of them marks it as `!important`?

If you just want to access the final CSS property for any element, consider using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead.

Comment: The application I am currently using it in has different css files for different themes, and only one is applied at a time. The issue this scenario has with getComputedStyle is that I'm creating a new object, and I don't always have an object to run getComputedStyle on to get a copy.
This is helpful for probably most other scenarios though. Thanks!